# AFNetworking check if image is cached

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, caching, afnetworking

I have this method, which downloads full size image for `UIImageView` when clicked on cell.

```
- (void)configureView
{
    NSURLRequest *URLRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:self.imageURL];

    AFImageRequestOperation *operation = [[AFImageRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:URLRequest];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

            [SVProgressHUD showSuccessWithStatus:@"Done!"];

        [self.imageView setImage:responseObject];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];

    [operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {
        float percentage = (totalBytesRead / (totalBytesExpectedToRead * 1.0f) * 100);
        NSLog(@"Percentage: %f", percentage);
        if (percentage != 100.0)
        {
            [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Downloading... %0.0f%%", percentage]];
        }
    }];

    [operation start];
}
```

So when download completes, `[SVProgressHUD showSuccessWithStatus:@"Done!"];` is called.
but when you go back to `tableViewController` and click on the same cell, `[SVProgressHUD showSuccessWithStatus:@"Done!"];` is called again even though the image is cached.
How can I check if the image is cached and only call `[SVProgressHUD showSuccessWithStatus:@"Done!"];` when it is not?

Answer (score 1):

AFImageRequestOperation doesn't cache images.  I think you are confusing AFNetworking's category "UIImageView+AFNetworking" with "AFImageRequestOperation".  The category does cache images, AFImageRequestOperation does not.

Comment: When I open the same cell the imageView is already loaded with downloaded image, why is that?

Comment: When I close and open the app and open the cell, image is not downloaded, it's there